# Apply transition by using min-width and max-width together

Tags: html, css, width, css-transitions

I have a nav bar for which I'm trying to make the toggle button work, my toggle button is a checkbox, so following is the css to make the navbar (`#navbar-left`) appear when you click on the checkbox

```
#navbar-left{
 max-width: 0;
 min-width: 0;
 width: 0;
 transition: max-width 0.2s ease;
 transition: min-width 0.2s ease;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ #navbar-left {
  max-width: 200%;
  min-width: 20%;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

where `.nav-trigger` is the check button, I have been able to either close the navbar smoothly using transition or open the navbar smoothly using transition by applying min-width or max-width at a time, but how can I use them both to open and close the navbar smoothly using the transitions.

I cannot simple apply the transitions using `width` property because I've to always set the `width` property to auto.

What would be the best solution or any alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be written within one single rule :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

> The transition CSS property is a shorthand property for transition-property, transition-duration, transition-timing-function, and transition-delay. It enables you to define the transition between two states of an element. Different states may be defined using pseudo-classes like :hover or :active or dynamically set using JavaScript.

> #Syntaxe

> /* Apply to 1 property */

> /* property name | duration */

> transition: margin-left 4s;

> /* property name | duration | delay */

> transition: margin-left 4s 1s;

> /* property name | duration | timing function | delay */

> transition: margin-left 4s ease-in-out 1s;

> **/ * Apply to 2 properties * /**

> transition: **margin-left** 4s, **color** 1s;

> /* Apply to all changed properties */

> transition: all 0.5s ease-out;

> /* Global values */

> transition: inherit;

> transition: initial;

> transition: unset;

```
#navbar-left{
 max-width: 0;
 min-width: 0;
 width: 0;
 transition: max-width 0.2s ease,min-width 0.2s ease;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ #navbar-left {
  max-width: 200%;
  min-width: 20%;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
```